# Html file load two different CSS files for desktop and mobile

Tags: html, css

I was asked to create a simple website for my assignment. I want the html file to run "mobile.css" when I open the site on mobile and run "desktop.css" when I open the site on mobile.

Comment: Please also post the code that you tried to achieve your goal... Just posting what you want is not really a good question :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Kokodoko I'm truly sorry but I have no idea which part of the code to publish. I think I need to do something with the <link href = ""> part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is misunderstood. I assume you want css to work for 'small' aka mobile, and big aka 'desktop'. This is done by css @media queries. This way, most likely we combine these styles in one css file.

e.g. change background for smaller resolution.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

If you want to detect if user uses mobile browser, you can detect it by css and conditionally load your css.

e.g.

```
const isMobile = navigator.userAgentData.mobile;
```

Answer (score 2):

The term "mobile" and "desktop" are very relative.

But you could use something like this to import your css files:

```
<link
   rel="stylesheet"
   href="your-mobile-css.css"
   media="screen and (max-width: 640px)"
/>
```

(and you could do the same for the desktop file)

The `link` element accepts a `media` attribute, which allows you to load the asset conditionally.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-media)

Another possibility would be for you to have a single css files and then use "media queries" to apply different styles for mobile and desktop devices.

You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)